# Cartesian product in java with two lists of hashmaps<String,String>

Tags: java, list, hashmap, cartesian-product

I'm trying to construct a cartesian product in java stored in d3 from d1 and d2, I'm getting an error that my + can't be used on two hashmap entrys. I want to join every entry in d1 with every entry in d2.

```
public static List<Map<String, String>> cartesianProduct(List<Map<String, String>> d1, List<Map<String, String>> d2) {
    List<Map<String, String>> d3 = new ArrayList<>();

    int s1 = d1.size();
    int s2 = d2.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < s1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < s2; j++) {
            d3.add(d1.get(i) + d2.get(j));
        }
    }

    return d3;
}
```

I've came this far, but I'm not able to join the content of the hashmaps together. Here I get the cartesian product but not joint in the same entry.

```
public static List<Map<String, String>> cartesianProduct(List<Map<String, String>> d1, List<Map<String, String>> d2) {
    List<Map<String, String>> result = new ArrayList<>();

    int s1 = d1.size();
    int s2 = d2.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < s1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < s2; j++) {
            d3.add(d1.get(i));
            d3.add(d2.get(j));
        }
    }

    return d3;
}
```

Example:

```
d1 = [{Year = 1976, PersonID = 1},
{Year = 1987, PersonID = 3},
{Year = 1974, PersonID = 2}]

d2 = [{PersonID = 0,houseID = H-101},
{PersonID = 1, houseID = H-202}]

d3 = [{Year = 1976, PersonID = 1,PersonID = 0,houseID = H-101},
{Year = 1976, PersonID = 1,PersonID = 1, houseID = H-202},
{Year = 1987, PersonID = 3,PersonID = 0,houseID = H-101},
{Year = 1987, PersonID = 3,PersonID = 1, houseID = H-202},
{Year = 1974, PersonID = 2,PersonID = 0,houseID = H-101},
{Year = 1974, PersonID = 2,PersonID = 1, houseID = H-202}]
```

Basically I need to join the values of the d1 and d2 together into one entry, how can this be done?

Comment: Please share examples with values. How do you join 2 hashmap ? You make one hashmap with 2 ?

Comment: A map can't have duplicate keys : that is the purpose of a Map. like not 2 PersonID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `Map.putAll`, to merge 2 maps into one

```
public static List<Map<String, String>> cartesianProduct(List<Map<String, String>> d1, 
                                                         List<Map<String, String>> d2) {
    List<Map<String, String>> d3 = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String, String> map3;

    for (int i = 0; i < d1.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < d2.size(); j++) {
            map3 = new HashMap<>();
            map3.putAll(d1.get(i));
            map3.putAll(d2.get(j));
            d3.add(map3);
        }
    }    
    return d3;
}
```

---

Could be nicer with foreach loops

```
Map<String, String> map3;
for (Map<String, String> i : d1) {
    for (Map<String, String> j : d2) {
        map3 = new HashMap<>();
        map3.putAll(i);
        map3.putAll(j);
        d3.add(map3);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you effort, but isn't it possible without using the hash library?

Comment: @greentea what "hash" library ? You mean "java code" ?

Comment: Your first code can't be compiled, even the second one.

Answer (score 0):

In your first Code, you declare d3 to be a List of (Maps from (String to String)).

```
List<Map<String, String>> d3 = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then you try to add a concatenation of 2 Strings, which is again a String(a single String) to d3, which expects a Map to be added.

```
for (int i = 0; i < s1; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < s2; j++) {
        d3.add(d1.get(i) + d2.get(j));
    }
}
```

In the second code, you declare a **result** in the same way, as above, but still refer to **d3**:

```
List<Map<String, String>> result = new ArrayList<>();

int s1 = d1.size();
int s2 = d2.size();

for (int i = 0; i < s1; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < s2; j++) {
        d3.add(d1.get(i));
        d3.add(d2.get(j));
    }
}
```

Test your code before sending it!

Then, your sample data looks like this:

```
d1 = [{Year = 1976, PersonID = 1},
{Year = 1987, PersonID = 3},
{Year = 1974, PersonID = 2}]
```

So there is a list of 3 Maps, each Map contains two pairs of String, the first element is in each case constantly "Year" and matches to an int, which is treated as String, the second is constantly "PersonID"?

This looks like a bad data structure choice. Like a simple class hiding in it, waiting for a name:

```
class PY {int year, int pid};
```

Analog for the relation pid, hid (houseId).

So this could be a list of 3 objects and a second one of 2 objects, easily to be combined. Maybe a Map (person -> year) and a map (house -> person) - we don't know whether one person may be related to two houses or one house to two persons or both.

It's a mess from ground up.